# How to create Silent Authentication in React Native using Auth0?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, auth0

I am on the first react native app on which I'm using Auth0 for authentication. What I'm trying to do is a silent authentication (refresh token)

I've already tried `checkSession()` but I'm getting this error:

> auth.checkSession() is not a function.

I've also tried to give to authorize prompt: 'none' parameter but it still opens the browser window and quickly close it back

```
auth.webAuth
    .authorize({
      prompt: "none",
      scope: "login",
      audience: AUDIENCE
    })
    .then(async credentials => {
      console.log(credentials);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: How did you achieved silent authentication? Can you share your experience please?

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to share our documentation on [Silent authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication)
as it may be able to help shed some light on what's going on. Please specifically checked your `.authorize` as it appears to be missing some core details discussed in the documentation.

I would also encourage you to check out [the quickstart available for React Native](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login) by Auth0.